# how to achieve MVC in my Zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework

currently i am doing a project in zend  the way i am doing is working perfectly but i am sure its not the way i am suppose to do i mean i am not following MVC and i want to apply MVC in my zend app.
i am pasting code of one simple module which will describe what i am doing .kindly correct me where i am making faults.

my controller

```
class ContactsController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

   public function contactsAction(){
    if(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
          $this->_redirect('login/login');
      }
      else{

       $request                = $this->getRequest();
       $user                   = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
       $phone_service_id       = $user->p_id;

       $instance               = new Contacts();
       $select                 = $instance->Get_Contacts($p_id);

       $adapter                = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
       $paginator              = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
       .
               .
       //more code
   }
```

plz note this 2 line in my controller

```
$instance               = new Contacts();
$select                 = $instance->Get_Contacts($pid);
```

this is my contacts class in models

```
class Contacts extends Zend_Db_Table{

function Get_Contacts($p_id){
    $DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

    $select = $DB->select()
         ->from('contact', array('contact_id','contact_first_name','contact_mobile_no','contact_home_no','contact_email','contact_office_no'))
         ->where('pid = ?', $p_id)
         ->order('date_created DESC');

         return $select;
    }
    }
```

after this i simple assign my result to my view.

**note please**
as its working but there is not private data members in my class,my class is not a blue print.there are no SETTERS AND GETTERS .how can i make my code that best suits MVC and OOP??

Comment: What is actually the reason you unaccepted by accepted answer and accepted another one which simply points to the manual? It's just the same link I provided in a comment to my much more thorough explanation :)

Comment: Are you aware that `extends` constitutes a "IS A" relationship. Contact is not database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep one thing in mind when u learn new technology so first read thier own documentation. No one can explain better than them. Its hard to understand firstly but when you study it you will usedto  and than u will love it like me [Zend Offical Site](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html)

Answer (score 3):

The most simple answer: you are already almost MVC. You use a Zend_Controller_Action to grab some data and pass this on to a view layer where you render the html. The only missing part is your model, which is mixed up between the controller and your data gateway (where you implemented a table data gateway pattern, that Zend_Db_Table thing).

I gave a pretty thorough explanation in an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789174/are-relatively-thick-controllers-normal-with-zend-form-and-if-not-how-does/7793267#7793267) how I'd properly set up the relations between Controller and Model. I also combined this with a Form, to handle data input, filtering and validation. Then to bundle some common functions, I introduced a Service layer between the Model and Controller.

With the controller, you perform some actions (list all my contacts, create a new contact, modify a contact) and the model is purely containing the data (id, name, phone, address). The service helps to group some functions (findContactByName, findContactById, updateContactWithForm).

If you know how to split Controller, Mode, Form and Service, your controller can become something like this:

```
class ContactsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        if (!$this->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->_redirect('login/login');
        }

        $service   = new Application_Service_Contacts;
        $contacts  = $service->getContacts();
        $paginator = $service->getPaginator($contacts);

        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    }

    protected function hasIdentity ()
    {
        return Zend_Auth::getInstance->hasIdentity();
    }
}
```

It is your personal taste what you want to do in your controller: I'd say you put as less as possible in your controllers, but you need to keep the control. So: a call to get data happens in the controller, retrieving this data happens somewhere else. Also: a call to convert a dataset into something else happens in the controller, the conversion happens somewhere else.

This way you can change the outcome in controllers extremely fast if you provided enough methods to your service classes to fetch the data. (Note I took the Zend_Auth to another function: if you have other actions, you can use this same function. Also, if you want to change something in your authentication, you have one place where this is located instead of every action in the controller)

Comment: thanQ very much sir what about my model and service here ??

Comment: You can have a look at the ZF quickstart where it is explained how you can create a model with a table data gateway pattern. The quickstart mentions a data mapper (in their example: Application_Model_GuestbookMapper) where I would prefer to put it into a separate subnamespace (Service) instead of Model, but the idea is the same: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html